# Calculating positive and negative values on a number line

Tags: java

I dont really know how to formulate my question, but Ill try. 
What I want to do is basically replace a sign in a userinput with an double value. The replcement process isnt relevant for now, my problem occurs when calculating the replacement. Imagine a number line with negative and positive numbers, eg. from -5 to 5 (`maxX` would be 10 then). 
Imagine `scale` as the stepwidth between my needed  replacements. So the replacements I would need to calculate will be: `-5.0, -4.8, -4.6, -4.4, [...], 4.4, 4.6, 4.8, 5.0` (because of: `n/scale = 0/5, 1/5, 2/5 [...]`). 
Heres my code (just for the calculation):

```
int maxX = 10;
int scale = 5; 

public void rep(){
double rep = 0; 
int n = 0;  
for (int k = (-maxX/2)*scale; k <= (maxX/2)*scale; k++){

    if (k < 0){
        rep = (double) n/scale +((int) ((k)/scale)); 
        System.out.println("k: "+k+"               "+rep);
    }

    if (k >= 0){
        rep = (double) n/scale +((int) ((k)/scale)); 
        System.out.println("k: "+k+"               "+rep);
    }

    if (n < scale-1){
        n++;
    } else {
        n = 0; 
    }

    }
}
```

It works fine, the results for `k => 0` match the requirements, but unfourtunatley the results for `k < 0` don't satify my needs because they are wrong (the console outprint):

```
k: -25               -5.0 // correct 
k: -24               -3.8 // wrong
k: -23               -3.6 // wrong
k: -22               -3.4 // wrong
k: -21               -3.2 // wrong
k: -20               -4.0 // correct
k: -19               -2.8
k: -18               -2.6
k: -17               -2.4
k: -16               -2.2
k: -15               -3.0
k: -14               -1.8
k: -13               -1.6
k: -12               -1.4
k: -11               -1.2
k: -10               -2.0
k: -9               -0.8
k: -8               -0.6
k: -7               -0.4
k: -6               -0.19999999999999996
k: -5               -1.0
k: -4               0.2
k: -3               0.4
k: -2               0.6
k: -1               0.8
k: 0               0.0
k: 1               0.2
k: 2               0.4
k: 3               0.6
k: 4               0.8
k: 5               1.0
k: 6               1.2
k: 7               1.4
k: 8               1.6
k: 9               1.8
k: 10               2.0
k: 11               2.2
k: 12               2.4
k: 13               2.6
k: 14               2.8
k: 15               3.0
k: 16               3.2
k: 17               3.4
k: 18               3.6
k: 19               3.8
k: 20               4.0
k: 21               4.2
k: 22               4.4
k: 23               4.6
k: 24               4.8
k: 25               5.0
```

What to change so the outputs for `k < 0` will match `-5.0, -4.8, -4.6, -4.4, [...]`, I cant wrap my head around it. Thank you.

Comment: All your integers are out of order. If you step through your own code, you will see why.

Comment: The problem is that you're using integer math so all results will be truncated, e.g. -24/5 will be truncated to -4 and if you add 0.2 to it this results in -3.8. Why do you calculate it like that anyways? Why not just add the step size in each iteration until the max value is hit? Something like `for(double v = -maxX/2; v <= maxX/2; v+=1.0/scale ) { System.out.println(v); }`

Comment: Ok, I see, it makes sense. Fix, because I need the integer value of this calculation to be -5 for -25 <= k < -20

Comment: Could you add a further explanation pls.

Comment: If you want to use your code try `(int)Math.floor((double)k/scale)` instead of `(k)/scale`.

Comment: Ok seems to work, you may post this as an official answer, Ill upvote and accept then. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your code try `(int)Math.floor((double)k/scale)` instead of `(k)/scale`.

Altneratively you could just add up 1/scale in the loop but due to precision issues you'd need to use BigDecimal:

```
int maxX = 10;
int scale = 5;
BigDecimal start = BigDecimal.valueOf( -maxX/2 );
BigDecimal end = BigDecimal.valueOf( maxX/2 );
BigDecimal step = BigDecimal.valueOf( 1.0/scale );
for( BigDecimal v = start; v.compareTo( end) <= 0; v = v.add( step ) ) 
{ 
  System.out.println("k:" + v.multiply( BigDecimal.valueOf( scale ) ).intValue() + "  " + v ); 
}
```